# binding syntax for @ObservationState in TCA

Tags: swift-composable-architecture

The old binding syntax was, (for example), `TextField("Name", text: viewStore.binding(get: \.text, send: { .updateText($0) }))`.

Since the `ViewStore` is no more, what's the new binding syntax?

Answer (score 1):

After digging into the Composable Architecture slack channel it appears that   `TextField("enter text here", text: $store.text.sending(\.updateText).animation()` is the new syntax.

This relies on decorating the `StoreOf<YourFeature>` with an `@State` or `@Bindable` property wrapper.

`animation()` can be omitted, or provided with an optional parameter.